# What is the meaning of % in this python expression

Tags: python, regex

Can someone explain what this regular expression means? I am looking at someone else's python code, and I just find myself curious as to what the expression is doing. I am also not certain what the 2nd % sign means.

```
regexStr = '(%s)' % '|'.join(['.*'.join(str(i) for i in p) for p in itertools.permutations(charList)])
```

Comment: have you tried running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it does this:

```
import itertools
charList = [1, 2, 3]

'(%s)' % '|'.join(['.*'.join(str(i) for i in p) for p in itertools.permutations(charList)])
#>>> '(1.*2.*3|1.*3.*2|2.*1.*3|2.*3.*1|3.*1.*2|3.*2.*1)'
```

First it generates all of the permutations of the input (unique orders):

```
for permutation in itertools.permutations(charList):
    print(permutation)
#>>> (1, 2, 3)
#>>> (1, 3, 2)
#>>> (2, 1, 3)
#>>> (2, 3, 1)
#>>> (3, 1, 2)
#>>> (3, 2, 1)
```

For each of these, it converts each item to a string and joins them with `.*`

```
'.*'.join(str(i) for i in (1, 2, 3))
#>>> '1.*2.*3'
```

Then it joins all of those with `|`

```
'|'.join(['.*'.join(str(i) for i in p) for p in itertools.permutations(charList)])
#>>> '1.*2.*3|1.*3.*2|2.*1.*3|2.*3.*1|3.*1.*2|3.*2.*1'
```

and finally uses `'(%s)' % result` to [wrap the result in brackets](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting):

```
'(%s)' % '|'.join(['.*'.join(str(i) for i in p) for p in itertools.permutations(charList)])
#>>> '(1.*2.*3|1.*3.*2|2.*1.*3|2.*3.*1|3.*1.*2|3.*2.*1)'
```

The pattern `'1.*2.*3'` matches all sequences like `111111222333333`.

The patern `A|B|C|D` matches *one* of `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`.

So the resulting regex matches any permutation, with each item repeated any number of times (including 0).

The outer brackets make this a capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Just try it with a test string. Let's try 'abc'

```
regexStr = '(%s)' % '|'.join(['.*'.join(str(i) for i in p) for p in itertools.permutations('abc')])

>>> regexStr
'(a.*b.*c|a.*c.*b|b.*a.*c|b.*c.*a|c.*a.*b|c.*b.*a)'
```

So it creates a `regex` search string, with each character of the permeated passed in string delimited by `'.*'` and each of the permutations delimeted by `'|'`.

If any of the steps within that line of code confuse you, look at the documentation for each component

[`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)
[`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
[`regex formatting`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)